# Pdfnet xamarin.ios doesn't print

Tags: xamarin.ios, pdftron, pdfnet

I'm working with Pdftron PdfNet libraries for Xamarin.iOS and introducing the print function:

```
if (UIPrintInteractionController.PrintingAvailable)
{
                var printerController = UIPrintInteractionController.SharedPrintController;

                var printInfo = UIPrintInfo.PrintInfo;
                printInfo.Duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplex.LongEdge;
                printInfo.OutputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General;
                printInfo.JobName = "Print";

                printerController.PrintInfo = printInfo;
                printerController.ShowsPageRange = true;

                var formatter = this.mPdfViewCtrl.ViewPrintFormatter;
                printerController.PrintFormatter = formatter;

                printerController.Present(true, (handler, completed, err) =>
                {
                    if (!completed && err != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Printer Error");
                    }
                });
}
```

Where mPdfViewCtrl is PDFViewCtrl type.

Now the problem is that the pages are printed all whites and no errors are triggered.
I think that the problem is the PDFViewCtrl ViewPrinterFormatter that has not the right data.
Has anyone had this promblem?

Answer (score 0):

This will be in the next release of PDFTron for Xamarin.iOS. Are you evaluating PDFTron, or working on a new release?

Comment: I'm evalueting it for a customer but I have to present results as soon as possible. When do you have scheduled the new release? Does exist a work arround for this problem now a day?

Comment: Yes, a beta is available now. Please contact pdftron support directly to get a link (I can't provide here sorry).